# Should I use type, if my "extends AnyVal" has not methods?

Tags: scala, types

The internet was not able to answer my question yet. Those two lines seem interchangeable to me:

```
type Meter = Double
class Meter(val d: Double) extends AnyVal
```

If Meter does not have any methods, should I use `type` instead? What's the difference?

Comment: The first is just an alias so `val x: Meter = 3.0` compiles whereas with the second definition it would not.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://jto.github.io/articles/type-all-the-things/. It is quite inspiring.

Comment: @Lee: Might be true, but it is not really that important to me whether I can write `=3.0` or have to write `new Meter(3.0)` - at least not in my back-end-code.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference?

Well, the obvious thing is that the first is simply a type alias, nothing more. The latter will attempt to unroll the wrapping class and use the underlying primitive directly. But, there are cases where `AnyVal` can't be unwrapped which are [stated in the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). For example, assume you wanted to pass `Meter` to a polymorphic function:

```
def identity[T](t: T): T = t
```

Passing `Meter` in would allocate an instance:

```
scala> class Meter(val d: Double) extends AnyVal
defined class Meter

scala> def identity[T](t: T): T = t
identity: [T](t: T)T

scala> :se -Xprint:typer

scala> identity(new Meter(1.0))

// Shortened this for brevity

private[this] val res0: Meter = $line4.$read.$iw.$iw.identity[Meter](new $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.Meter(1.0));
<stable> <accessor> def res0: Meter = $iw.this.res0
```

On the other hand, `type Meter` will always yield a `Double`:

```
scala> type Meter = Double
defined type alias Meter

scala> val m: Meter = 1.0
m: Meter = 1.0

scala> def identity[T](t: T): T = t
identity: [T](t: T)T

scala> :se -Xprint:uncurry

scala> identity(m)
private[this] val res1: Double = $line5.$read.$iw.$iw.identity[Double]($line4.$read.$iw.$iw.m());
<stable> <accessor> def res1(): Double = $iw.this.res1
```

Another sensitivity is that if you allocate an `Array[Meter]`, an instance will need to be allocated.

There are differences between the two. Which one should you use? As usually, it depends. If type safety is of outter importance to you and you don't mind the edge cases where one occurs an extra allocation, go with the class. If you have a rather complex type you want to abstract over, for example a `Either[String, A]` where you want to make the type simpler, perhaps a `type Foo[A] = Either[String, A]` would be simpler to understand and more intuitive.

Comment: Sooo... in your example with Meter the type is superior, because it could be unrolled and is thus results in faster bytecode? What is your conclusion? Should I use type?

Comment: Not sure what faster bytecode is, but it will occur one allocation less. Does that really matter? I don't know. It really depends on your use case. There is no ultimate "do this or that", just facts.

Comment: Speed is pretty important in my case because there will be a lot of instances of some of my types (those I am talking about). Because of the amount of instances I also aim for as little memory consumption as possible (=sensible).

Comment: @Make42 You should also note that if you store `Meter` in an `Array` it will need to allocate an instance, if that's important.

Comment: Do you mean in the case of the class? And that is not the case if I use a type? What is the "rule" behind your example? When is the class not unboxed?

Comment: Also: Wouldn't inheritance be a difference? I could use two classes (with underlaying int and underlaying double) that inherit both from a new class Number or something like that. Than I could build collections of this new class Number. That is not possible with type, right?

Comment: If you build collections of `Number`, you need allocations again.

Comment: Ok, but forget the collection for a moment: The inheritance does not work with types, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a type alias, you are not creating any new types, just another name for an existing type

`type Meter = Double`

Meter here is still just another name for Double now.  The two are interchangeable.  You could use Meter anywhere you need a Double and vise-versa

When instead you use

`class Meter(val value: Double) extends AnyVal`

Now you've created an entirely new type.  It's no longer interchangeable with Double.  It just has some optimizations to just use the underlying value instead of instantiating the wrapper class when it isn't needed, but as far as code is concerned it is entirely separate from Double.

So use an alias when you just need a different name for something and use a value class when you want to  use a different type for a value.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK those two lines are not interchangeable. `type`s are used as aliases like in this example:

```
type User = String
type Age = Int

val data:  Map[User, Age] =  Map.empty
```

Extending `AnyVal` on the other side has nothing to do with type aliasing. It has impact on boxing/unboxing of numerical values.

Comment: As far as I understand, in JVM bytecode, the AnyVal is represented solely by the underlying type - in my case a Double. Thus I have no performance loss.