# When are classes extending AnyVal not unboxed?

Tags: scala

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/40486805/4533188 I was told that classes extending `AnyVal` cannot be unboxed by the compiler (so that there are only the underlaying primitives in the JVM bytecode) in some cases. What are all the rules when unboxing does not work?

I understand that if a class extending AnyVal is put into a collection, that then the unboxing does not work. I also was given an example with generics, but I would like to understand the whole picture.

Comment: That answer already links documentation which gives these rules.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Ah, sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation is pretty clear on these occasions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

> ### Allocation Summary
>
> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> - a value class is treated as another type.
> - a value class is assigned to
>   an array.
> - doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Example of a value class is treated as another type:

```
trait Distance extends Any
case class Meter(val value: Double) extends AnyVal with Distance

def add(a: Distance, b: Distance): Distance = ???
add(Meter(3.4), Meter(4.3))
```

Example of a value class assigned to an array:

```
val arrayOfMeter: Array[Meter] = ???
```

Example of pattern matching:

```
val p: Meter = new Meter(1.0)
p match {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: But did you say in your answer of the other question that if you put a AnyVal into a collection, it would not be unboxed? Here it only mentions Arrays to have this effect. Would it be unboxed with e.g. a List?